Parent a point from one object to another object?
I have three objects in my scene:

circle called nurbsCircle1
a straight line called curve1
another straight line called curve2

I want one end of these straight line objects to always move along with the circles middle points (left and right). Even if the circle is scaled, the points of the lines always move with it, with the other end of the lines remaining stationery. Something like this 
I tried figuring it out on my own and did not manage it, searching online I was pointed to Geometry constraints but this did not help me.
I am very new to Maya and I am just trying to learn it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
